# header2.el: insert header between second and third row?

Tags: file-header

I customized my own header and want it to be inserted between the second and the third line of the document. Unfortunately I'm not very used to Lisp, therefore I have a hard time trying to find the corresponding lines in [`header2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el). Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

As the Commentary of [`header2.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/header2.el) says:

```
;; To have Emacs update file headers automatically whenever you save a
;; file, put this in your init file (~/.emacs):
;;
;;   (autoload 'auto-update-file-header "header2")
;;   (add-hook 'write-file-hooks 'auto-update-file-header)
;;
;; To have Emacs add a file header whenever you create a new file in
;; some mode, put this in your init file (~/.emacs):
;;
;;   (autoload 'auto-make-header "header2")
;;   (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'auto-make-header)
;;   (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook   'auto-make-header)
```

If you want the header to contain two lines of your choice as its first two lines then just define a function that inserts those two lines, and put that function at the beginning of option `make-header-hook`.  E.g.:

```
(defun insert-my-first-two-lines ()
  (insert "MY FIRST LINE")
  (insert "MY SECOND LINE"))

M-x customize-option make-header-hook
```

Click `INS` in Customize at the beginning of the default value of `make-header-hook`, to insert `insert-my-first-two-lines`:

```
INS DEL insert-my-first-two-lines
```

Save your customization.

Automatic updating of the header, by `update-file-header`, will do nothing to those first two lines (which I guess is what you want).  It changes only lines for which you have defined an updating action using `register-file-header-action`.